# Element has a set height, if inner elements overflows Y - transfer to the new column

Tags: css

I need something similar to `flex-wrap: wrap` but for the height, when inner content overflows height of the parent element, transfer to the new column. Is there some command that can do so in CSS? 
Example: 

5 and 6 don't fit in the `wrapper`, so I need them to be transferred to the next column.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 95px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-content">1</div>
  <div class="inner-content">2</div>
  <div class="inner-content">3</div>
  <div class="inner-content">4</div>
  <div class="inner-content">5</div>
  <div class="inner-content">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Note this **only** works with a fixed height.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 95px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner-content">1</div>
  <div class="inner-content">2</div>
  <div class="inner-content">3</div>
  <div class="inner-content">4</div>
  <div class="inner-content">5</div>
  <div class="inner-content">6</div>
</div>
```